# Access form input in the same form

Tags: php

I am taking input from user in a form. Can I get that value(user input) to calculate other fields in the same form.

```
<input size="12" id="inputField" name="inputField"  autofocus="" type="date"     onblur="return dateValidate(this)"/>
```

Can I collect this form input later in the form and use it to calculate other fields. I was trying to using to use `$_POST` to retrieve the value but I am not sure if thuis is the right thing.

Comment: Simple answer: With AJAX, yes.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do it in PHP before submitting the form. You can easily do so in  JavaScript. However you could simply add some AJAX code to send the value to your PHP script when user enters something in the box, and parse the response accordingly. PHP works on server side, and does not interact with user without any server side request

Answer (score 2):

You can certainly do it in 2 ways...

1st way

```
<?php
$first_digit = '';
$second_digit = '';
$third_digit = '';

if(isset($_POST['calculate'])) {
   $first_digit = $_POST['first_digit'];
   $second_digit = $_POST['second_digit'];
   $third_digit = $first_digit + $second_digit;
}
?>

<form method="POST">
   <input type="text" name="first_digit" value="<?php if(isset($first_digit)) echo $first_digit; ?>" />

   <input type="text" name="second_digit" value="<?php if(isset($second_digit)) echo $second_digit; ?>" />

   <input type="text" name="third_digit" readonly value="<?php if(isset($third_digit)) echo $third_digit; ?>" />

   <input type="submit" name="calculate" value="Calculate" />
</form>
```

2nd Way

Total the variables in the code and instead of showing the result output in a text box you can instead calculate and echo out the result, or you can store that in the database.

Note: Be sure you keep the third `input[type=text]` as `readonly` as it is showing you the calculated value so probably you don't want your users to change

Comment: Thnx or the comment. I tried something in the lines of your code like below:

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can get input from user to calculate other fields in the same form, you should use scripts like `OnChange()` or `onClick()` to have this.